# Order Results in Search Driven Content for Picture Webpart

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

I'm using search driven content for picture webpart to show some pictures.

[image]

Is it possible to order the results by a field like regular search webpart? For some reasons, the webpart does not show the Sorting tab in Build Your Query popup.

[image]

Is the Sorting tab not in this case by design? Or because of SP2013 version? Or do I have to turn on some settings?

Anyone knows how to order the results of the pictures? Maybe use a different column?